# No such file or directory error when executing sql file from \i command in PosqtgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, bitnami

I am currently working on **PostgreSQL (Bitnami)** docker container an I am unable to execute a db script which is in `.sql` format from `\i file-path` command in psql. I searched many times but I could not find an answer for this. The PostgreSQL version is 10.12.0.

Comment: What does "unable to execute" mean? Is the file not found?

Comment: And can you use the full path name? And is the file in your container, or on the host where you run "psql"?

Comment: @A.Scherbaum yes. It says file cannot be found. I used the full path from the root. The file is in my local machine file system.

Comment: But you are running psql in the Docker container, which is not the same system.

Comment: That means I need to move my script file into the docker image?

Comment: Yes. How else can tools in your container access the file?

Comment: It worked. Could you please add this as an answer? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .sql file you want to \i include must be in the Docker container, not on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Late but for posterity, if you are still facing problems after relocating your file to your docker container (or running postgres/psql from your local m/c), another thing you can check for is your file path (remove spaces).

yourdb-#\i path/to/dest/with/no/filename/spaces/script.sql;

ought to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for giving an answer, but the chances are that if a user has thumbed up another answer half a year ago then this is probably redundant.